# crystal reports group data as a summary without showing row details

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I group data in crystal report? 
I see a lot of examples to group it. but it has the order detail on each group. Or it has the detail row for each month/country. I just need the summary per month/country or per order (and so on). I don't need the row details.

I tried hide (drill down ok) and supress (no drill down) 
but I still get the report looking like this.

Here I want the report to just show me the summary for each country. I want to collapse the customer name row details. I am coming from SSRS, and in ssrs we can do this using matrix and just remove the detail line.

[image: Here I want the report to just show me the summary for each country. I want to collapse the customer name row details]

Thank you

Comment: You want GH1 and GF1 on the same row? You can try hiding Details, then on GH1 check on underlay following section: http://flylib.com/books/en/4.229.1.68/1/ - you can also look at Inserting Cross Tabs (like Pivot Table in Excel)

Comment: What do you want to do specifically?

Comment: Have you tried to supress the Details Section and still getting this result?. Can you show us also a screenshot of your Select Expert with Details Section selected?

Comment: ignore GF1 , I just need GH1 showing up on the report. later I will show the sum total on GH1. Hide D, I don't want D to show up.  is this possible without crosstab?